# Disks shows two external HDDs as one

Tags: 20.04, disk

I use Ubuntu 20.04 with two external HDDs, both in Sabrent EC-DFFN USB3 cases. I can mount them and access files in Caja, but Disks only sees one drive. If I mount them one at a time, the serial numbers are different and sizes are correct 1TB, or 2TB.

If both are mounted at the same time, only one is shown and the size is the size of the last HDD mounted.

`fdisk-l` output:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 9.7 MiB, 9510912 bytes, 18576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 96.52 MiB, 101191680 bytes, 197640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 54.98 MiB, 57626624 bytes, 112552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 54.97 MiB, 57618432 bytes, 112536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 160.16 MiB, 167931904 bytes, 327992 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 161.42 MiB, 169254912 bytes, 330576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 105.3 MiB, 110403584 bytes, 215632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 111.81 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk model: Corsair Force LS
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa7c40be5

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 234440703 234438656 111.8G 83 Linux




Disk /dev/loop8: 105.29 MiB, 110399488 bytes, 215624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 62.9 MiB, 65105920 bytes, 127160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 62.3 MiB, 65323008 bytes, 127584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 16 KiB, 16384 bytes, 32 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 14.89 MiB, 15589376 bytes, 30448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 14.89 MiB, 15589376 bytes, 30448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 7.95 MiB, 8310784 bytes, 16232 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop15: 7.94 MiB, 8306688 bytes, 16224 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop16: 54.84 MiB, 57479168 bytes, 112264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop17: 16 KiB, 16384 bytes, 32 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop18: 88.28 MiB, 92565504 bytes, 180792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop19: 96.101 MiB, 101695488 bytes, 198624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model:                 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C14A5E6C-471D-44D6-9D94-0D004B39BB0B

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdc: 1.84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model:                 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: AC20240E-7621-4A27-8DBE-8CF8F0F51715

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 3907028991 3907026944  1.8T Linux filesystem
```

`lsblk -f` output:

```
NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/cano
loop2
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/core
loop3
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/core
loop4
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/core
loop5
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gnom
loop6
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gnom
loop7
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/plex
loop8
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/plex
loop9
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gtk-
loop10
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/smar
loop11
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/soft
loop12
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/ubun
loop13
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/ubun
loop14
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/puls
loop15
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/puls
loop16
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gtk-
loop17
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/soft
loop18
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/mcom
loop19
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/core
sda                                                                   
└─sda1
     ext4         68230819-5a81-43ea-a3cf-3211626b2c94     67G    34% /
sdb                                                                   
└─sdb1
     ext4   1TB   faeae341-9f6d-4642-aeeb-580dd6667fc0  869.2G     0% /media/awa
sdc                                                                   
└─sdc1
     ext4         b5ac84e0-5f7d-44a0-8f52-3034ffa0d404                
sr0
```

Comment: A screenshot would help...

Comment: Did you clone one to the other? As they should have different UUIDs and if gpt partitioned different GUIDs. If cloned they you cannot mount both at same time as duplicate UUIDs not allowed.

Comment: Mate desktop if it matters. No not cloned ,both recently re formatted and empty. UUIDs are different and Ubuntu sees them with different numbers.

Comment: Sorry don't know how to do screenshot here ,I get /home/awarre1/Desktop/Screenshot at 2020-07-19 03-47-07.png

Comment: 2TB is /media/awarre1/58F7-ACFD  1TB is faeae341-9f6d-4642-aeeb-580dd6667fc0

Comment: Add the output of `fdisks -l` and `lsblk -f` to your question (use "edit")